# WCF Collection returns empty

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I am new and just for a while in WCF. I have created small ServiceContract as below:

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IStudents
    {
        [OperationContract]
        List<Student> GetStudents();

        [OperationContract]
        bool Add(Student stud);
    }
```

With DataContract :

```
[DataContract(Name = "Students")]
public class Student
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double Rating { get; private set; }

    public Student(string name, double rating)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Rating = rating;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Name}, {Rating}";
    }
}
```

I have also WPF project where UI allows to add or show students. When button is clicked I add student with Service and displaying list. I am debugging also host so I see there are students in collection but when it goes back to WPF collection is empty. Here is piece of WPF code

//MainWindow

```
public StudentsClient Service { get; set; }  = new StudentsClient("BasicHttpBinding_IStudents");
```

//button clicks method:

```
  Service.Add(new Student(NameBox.Text, Convert.ToDouble(RateBox.Text)));
  GetStudentsAsync();
```

GetStudentAsync method:

```
  private async void GetStudentsAsync()
        {
            InfoTextBlock.Text = "Getting studs..";
            var studs = await Service.GetStudentsAsync(); // studs collection is empty there
            Students = new ObservableCollection<Student>(studs);
            StudentListView.ItemsSource = Students;
            InfoTextBlock.Text = "";
        }
```

Does anyone know where do I make mistake ?

PS. Is it problem if I have Student model class with the same attributes as in Serice. Do I have to make it in shared class libary?

EDIT:

```
 public class Students : IStudents
    {
        public List<Student> GetStudents()
        {
            return Database.AllStudents;
        }

        public bool Add(Student stud)
        {
            Database.AllStudents.Add(stud);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post the code of the GetStudents operation contract.

Comment: Have you tested your service with some other client? e.g. WCF Testing Client tool.

Comment: Noo as I said it just quick project. I thought it might be common issue

Comment: It will just help to rule out the client from the picture. If you are getting empty result in testing tool too it is your central code which is doing something wrong.

Comment: Its a bit strange because I see that AllStudents collection has x elements and after its empty

Comment: Is `Database` a static class or property in the `Students` class?